# Using Material UI in React and JS

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, material-ui

Ok my issue is when I use React and Material UI I get the error posted in the picture.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";


function Header() {
   return (
    <div className="header">
        <h1>I am a header the beginnings of a website</h1>
        <MenuIcon ></MenuIcon>
    </div>
 );
}

export default Header;
```

I have followed the error to the location and it is:

```
export { default } from './SvgIcon';
```

I have went through the complete setup again to see if I missed anything. However everything is just up to date. When I remove the `import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";` and remove the `MenuIcon>` from the Header my site shows.

I am lost on this issue. I have tried locating what it means by `not found in react`. I have been using `npm` to install everything.

I have installed every npm install on the `https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/` website and I am at a loss.

What am I missing?

*****Update*****

Ok after starting a new React and JS I still get the same error. I can add anything to the website I am building as anything except Material UI.. I am beginning to wander if Material UI is the problem and not what I am doing.

I can add icons with other routes. However Material UI and following the documentation and their samples still don't show the icons. It just makes the entire website blank.

When I remove all references to Material UI the website shows again. So I am wondering if anyone else has ran into this. I am using all update methods with Visual Code, Node.js and everything used in the website is up to date.

So I am wondering if it's a compatibility issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the icons? https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/

`npm install @mui/icons-material`

Comment: yes i have installed it

Comment: i just installed it again and all it did was say `up to date`

Answer (score 0):

The code looks right.

Are you sure, that you installed the mui libary in the right folder?
The src, public and node_modules folder should be all in the same directory.

Maybe delete the node_modules folder, package.json, package-lock.json and install the dependencies again.

I think a better alternative to the MUI Icons is Iconify. You should definitly check it out.
https://iconify.design/

You can easily import icons with somethink like:
`<Iconify icon='eva:heart'/>`

Comment: I have thought about scraping the project and starting over since I am not that far into it.. I am just at the blank page you see the header but once you try to add the menu icon it screams at me all the errors. So I am gonna try a blank slate and start all over

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after further analysis I have found the issue. When I was installing the `npx install method` Somehow it was misconfigured. When I `CD` into the file name it was not going to root project.

After I made sure i was in the root project and I installed the npm again everything is working fine.

Solution:

```
cd file-name
```

then you do all the installation. For some reason when I was installing the libraries it was installing outside of `cd file-name`